# Way to identify API usage and limits using API?

Tags: api, limits

Is there an API method to return how much API calls were used and how much total calls is allowed by my SF org?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's currently no API access to see the API call counts/limits. You can run a report that shows usage over the last 7 days (see the administrative reports section)

Comment: that's unfortunate. we build an apex app, so we have access only to API, not Salesforce org itself

Comment: You can also see the API usage in the Company Information section, although this again is also on the org itself.

Comment: Can you setup the app in a development org? They're free...

Comment: This is now accessible at `/services/data/v34.0/limits`.

Answer (score 1):

**System Overview**

Go to Setup | Quick Find System Overview and there you will find the API REQUESTS, LAST 24 HOURS. This shows you how many API calls you've made in the last 24 hours including today. For example, if you are viewing this on Monday at 2:30 PM, it'll show you the calls made since Sunday at 2:30 PM.

**The "API Usage last 7 days" report**

NOTE: 'View Setup and Configuration' permission on your profile is required to see this report.

The 'API Usage last 7 days' report shows you the calls made by user and date for the last 7 days including today. Take into account that the counters for this report reset at 12am Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) or UTC.

**Event logging**

For more granular information, Event logging can be used. Refer to our SOAP API Developer Guide for more information.

**Use Limits from REST API**

/services/data/v43.0/limits

Use **Event Monitoring** to check API Usage