# How to tell 24 hour API usage vs limit

Tags: api

Is there any way to query the 24 hour rolling api call usage?  I'd like to build in some logic around what to skip if/when I breach 80% of my API usage allotted for that 24 hour period...

Comment: Potentially relevant [post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/way-to-identify-api-usage-and-limits-using-api?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson I've seen those posts, but they are all old.  That one is from 2012, and I'm hoping there's some new functionality/hacks out there that could help with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are both REST API and SOAP API mechanisms to get this information.

The REST endpoint that will give you the information you need is the `limits` endpoint:

```
GET: /services/data/v34.0/limits
```

That returns (among other things) `DailyApiRequests` both max and current values.

[image: Calling the limits REST endpoint]

Pretty sure that is a relatively recent addition...like within the past year.

For SOAP integrations, Chapter 12 of the SOAP API guide details the `LimitInfoHeader`, which contains the API request limit current and maximum usage for that org. As of the current release, Summer 15, this feature is in Pilot.

Comment: There's also a SOAP header that provides the same functionality.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar!  I hadn't heard of that endpoint yet, but it's going to make my year!  I've already integrated it, and it seems to work flawlessly!  I have a job that runs every ten minutes to refresh a custom setting that replicates the structure of what I get back from that endpoint, so that I don't have to call it EVERY time I make an outbound call, but keeps the data live-enough!

Comment: It would be interesting to composite up that call with other calls, though using the batch endpoint. Gives me a good idea for a blog post, in fact.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't played with batch endpoint yet.  Is that just for inbound?  Or can I use it to batch outbound as well?

Comment: You can bundle two REST calls into one JSON POST request. So, in this instance, you could bundle the `limits` call with a query call, and have the current state of limits come back with your query results. A clever transport layer might automatically do that every 10 minutes or so and then cache that information locally.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Limits` class, specifically [`getCallouts`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_Limits_getCallouts) and [`getLimitCallouts`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_Limits_getLimitCallouts).

```
Integer remainingCallouts = Limits.getLimitCallouts() - Limits.callouts();
```

Comment: Already tried that in Dev Console... Limits.getLimitCallouts() = 100, which is not correct.  I think that's the per-context value, not the rolling-24 hours value