# Retrieve API calls number from API

Tags: api, governorlimits, limits

I'm currently running large processes, and I'm afraid the limit of my API calls is not enough to handle that. I want to retrieve my current number of API calls (and my maximum API calls), to verify that I never exceed my maximum - 5000 (margin of safety).

How to recover these 2 numbers?

Comment: I found on this post that it is impossible. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/way-to-identify-api-usage-and-limits-using-api?rq=1